# What does "butt in excessively" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "butt in excessively" mean?

> I am just trying to be friends with the transfer student, but you are **butting in excessively**.

Comment: I think it depends on what *"trying to be friends"* means. See ['cramping my style'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10714/what-does-cramp-ones-style-mean).

Comment: It largely means "trying to interfere with your nonsense."

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about "*butt in*"?

Answer (score 1):

[**Butt in**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butt_in) means:

> (Idiomatic) To join a conversation or situation in which one is not
>   welcome or invited; to interject (connotes a rude or discourteous
>   interruption). [Wiktionary]

Hey, this is none of your business, don’t *butt in*! Forgive me for *butting in*.